Antipode and primitive element in a Hopf algebra
Let $(H, \mu, \eta, \Delta, \varepsilon, S)$ be a Hopf algebra (with the usual notations) over a commutative field $k$ of characteristic zero (for simplicity).
We know that if $x \in H$ is a primitive element (i.e. $\Delta(x) = x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x$) then it satisfies $S(x) = -x$ and $\varepsilon(x) = 0$.
So, I was wondering if the converse is true and if not
(a) is there a good counterexample ?
(b) what other condition(s) one may add to make it true ?
So far, my attempt is as follows: let $x \in H$ such that $S(x) = -x$ and $\varepsilon(x) = 0$. Then by the antipode identity
$$\mu \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes S) \circ \Delta (x) = \eta \circ \varepsilon(x) = 0.$$
We denote $\Delta(x) = \lambda^\prime \otimes x + x \otimes \lambda^{\prime\prime} + \sum_{x^\prime \neq \lambda^\prime, x^{\prime\prime} \neq \lambda^{\prime\prime}} x^\prime \otimes x^{\prime\prime}$, where $\lambda^\prime, \lambda^{\prime\prime} \in k$ and the purpose would be to show that $\lambda^\prime = \lambda^{\prime\prime} = 1$ and that the summation is zero.
We have
\begin{align*}
\mu \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes S) \circ \Delta (x) & = \mu \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes S)\left(\lambda^\prime \otimes x + x \otimes \lambda^{\prime\prime} + \sum_{x^\prime \neq \lambda^\prime, x^{\prime\prime} \neq \lambda^{\prime\prime}} x^\prime \otimes x^{\prime\prime}\right) \\
& = \lambda^\prime S(x) + \lambda^{\prime\prime}x + \sum_{x^\prime \neq \lambda^\prime, x^{\prime\prime} \neq \lambda^{\prime\prime}} x^\prime S(x^{\prime\prime}) \\
& = (\lambda^{\prime\prime} - \lambda^{\prime}) x + \sum_{x^\prime \neq \lambda^\prime, x^{\prime\prime} \neq \lambda^{\prime\prime}} x^\prime S(x^{\prime\prime})
\end{align*}
which implies that
$$(\lambda^{\prime} - \lambda^{\prime\prime}) x = \sum_{x^\prime \neq \lambda^\prime, x^{\prime\prime} \neq \lambda^{\prime\prime}} x^\prime S(x^{\prime\prime}).$$
On the other hand, if we use the counit identity we have
$$(\mathrm{id} \otimes \varepsilon) \circ \Delta(x) = x.$$
Then, with the same convention for $\Delta(x)$ as above, we obtain
\begin{align*}
(\varepsilon \otimes \mathrm{id}) \circ \Delta(x) & = (\varepsilon \otimes \mathrm{id})\left(\lambda^\prime \otimes x + x \otimes \lambda^{\prime\prime} + \sum_{x^\prime \neq \lambda^\prime, x^{\prime\prime} \neq \lambda^{\prime\prime}} x^\prime \otimes x^{\prime\prime}\right) \\
&= \lambda^{\prime} x + \sum_{x^\prime \neq \lambda^\prime, x^{\prime\prime} \neq \lambda^{\prime\prime}} \varepsilon(x^\prime) x^{\prime\prime} 
\end{align*}
which implies that
$$(1-\lambda^{\prime}) x = \sum_{x^\prime \neq \lambda^\prime, x^{\prime\prime} \neq \lambda^{\prime\prime}} \varepsilon(x^\prime) x^{\prime\prime}$$
Applying $S$ on both sides we obtain
$$(\lambda^{\prime}-1) x = \sum_{x^\prime \neq \lambda^\prime, x^{\prime\prime} \neq \lambda^{\prime\prime}} \varepsilon(x^\prime) S(x^{\prime\prime}).$$
We can also write the antipode and counit identities by swaping with the identity, but so far I do not have a conclusion with these computations. Any hint would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

In the tensor algebra, $x^3 = x \otimes x \otimes x$ (for $x \in V$) satisfies $S\left(x^3\right) = -x^3$ and $\epsilon\left(x^3\right) = 0$, but is not primitive.

Yes, indeed, nice counterexample ! Is any additional condition known which would make this statement true. So far, I didn't find anything.

@darijgrinberg Sounds like an answer to me.

Following up on @darijgrinberg's comment: if $x$ is primitive and $n>1$ is odd, then $S(x^n) = (-1)^n x^n = -x^n$. So if there are any primitive elements and we're working in characteristic zero, then the $n$th power of each primitive will satisfy your property. Note that the $n$th power $x^n$ of a primitive is not primitive in characteristic zero unless $x^n$ is zero.
So if you want $S(y) = -y$ and $\epsilon(y)=0$ to imply that $y$ is primitive, then for any primitive $x$ you must have $x^n=0$ for every odd $n$, which means that every primitive must itself be zero in your Hopf algebra.

Thank you for your nice answer. If I understand correctly your reasoning, this implies that one has to take a Hopf algebra where zero is the only primitive element so that if one has $x$ such that $S(x) = - x$ and $\varepsilon(x) = 0$ then $x$ primitive, right ?

Yes, at least in characteristic zero. In characteristic two, for example, you could have a nonzero primitive $x$, but it would have to satisfy $x^2=0$.
